# ColdFusion 11 console doesn't use Windows service wrapper to start app server

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a ColdFusion11 environment with two app servers defined. The default cfusion server was created with a Windows system service wrapper to go along with it; the second app server, for some reason, was not.

The SC tool was later used to create a Windows service wrapper for the second app server; however, when the 2nd app server is controlled within the cfusion Enterprise Manager instance, it does not use the Windows Service wrapper to control it. Is there a configuration file I can amend that will instruct CF to invoke the Windows service wrapper to control this second service? This is particularly important as this 2nd server instance has a logon identity that must be used at startup, but if the server is restarted within the CF console, the identity is obviously not used.

In effect, I need to tell the cfusion enterprise manager to use the Windows service wrapper to control the 2nd app server instance, *not* to just control it directly. I'm assuming there is a configuration setting buried deep within the bowels of CF that would allow me to specify this.

I've tried searching the XML configuration files, looking for a non-obvious setting within them that might point to a startup configuration parameter, but so far have found nothing. *Something* must control how a secondary app server is managed, so I thought I'd ask here for some insight.

Comment: When you created the second instance, did you check the "Create Windows Service" checkbox on the initial screen in the admin? What is the _SC tool_?

Comment: No, the second instance was created by someone else, and the Create Windows Service tab was not checked. That's the problem. The SC (service creation) utility (it's a fairly old Windows tool) to create a service was used to "manually" build a service wrapper for the 2nd instance - which is fairly standard practice as I've seen on various CF11 support sites and Adobe forums for this situation. No idea why the original installation was not done w/o the service.

Comment: Gotcha. So does stopping the created Windows service not stop the second instance?

Comment: If it was *started* that way, yes. If it is started *within the cfusion enterprise manager* console GUI, no - the service won't even show as "started", and if someone tries to start it (not realizing it's really running), you'll get a startup error (understandably). That says to me that the admin console startup is not using the service wrapper version.

Comment: Wow, you just hit an old-dimly-lit brain cell.I remember having that same issue a long time ago. Sorry, but I don't think we ever got it working. We just always used the Windows Service to stop/start and did not use the admin interface. Apologies, I know that doesn't help you but hopefully these additional details will help others finding this post.

Comment: No problem, Miguel-F, thanks for the assist nonetheless.

Comment: Miguel-f - just as an FYI, I actually did find the answer to the problem. Answer added below; thought you might be interested.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of anyone else who might encounter this situation, I've discovered the answer. It has nothing to do with changing the configuration of the application server itself.

When the ColdFusion11 administrator console is told to start an instance of another application server within the Enterprise Manager, it first queries the Windows Service Control database for a defined service of the ***exact name*** "ColdFusion 11 Application Server [AppServerName]" (without the brackets). If it finds such a service, CF automatically invokes the service wrapper and starts it. Absent that, a direct invocation of the CF instance commences.

The solution to the issue for an app server created without a Windows service wrapper is, when the 'sc' utility is invoked to create the service, to provide a service name that exactly matches the format above.

Comment: Nice sleuthing David! Thank you for coming back and answering so others can benefit as well.  Cheers